# Stop Chrome from using ISP-specific "page not found" page?

Tags: google-chrome

When I try to navigate to a website that doesn't exist, I see this:

[image]

When I should be seeing this~

[image]

I can't find anything in settings to disable Verizon's takeover of this. How can I change it?

Comment: That is likely a result of using Verizon's DNS servers. Try deleting those and using others (1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 spring to mind but there are many others) There is no specific reason you *have to* use the DNS servers your ISP provides

Comment: DNS servers needs to be changed in the router.

Answer (score 2):

This will be because of your default DNS that you are using. To stop this, I would use one of these [Public DNS Servers](https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062)

To learn how to change your DNS in Windows see this [Windows Central Article on changing your DNS](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10)

The reason this is happening is because you are currently using a *Verizon DNS*. A DNS (in simple terms) translates a websites domain name (e.g. example.com) into an ip address that you can connect to (e.g. 93.184.216.34). It basically makes the task of connecting to a website much easier. While many DNS's simply just don't route you to a 'website could not be found' page if you can't connect, some do, like yours. So the only way to stop this would be to change your DNS to another one that doesn't. To my knowledge, I don't believe any on the list above do this.

It's not Chrome that decides whether this happens or not - it could happen on any browser you use - it's the Domain Name System.

Comment: While corrrect, I think you should also add some explanation on _why_ DNS makes this happen and why it's not Chrome's decision.